# Android Textview moves other views out of the layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

In my layout I need to have a textview with two buttons next to that and one cancel button at right side (refer below image)[image]

But when the text view is too long then the buttons near to the textview goes behind the cancel button(refer the below image)
 [image]

Attached xml file for your reference,

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World, MActivity"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="yes" />
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="no" />
</LinearLayout>
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="cancel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Set a fixed width for your textview

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked multiple times, but there should have no basic layout solution to handle this. You have to write custom code to completely solve this problem.

You can use a workaround, set `android:maxWidth` for TextView

e.g.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="150dp"/>
```